# Diagonal matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let $D$ be a 3-by-3 positive definite diagonal matrix, so all 3 diagonal entries are positive. Then is it possible to find all solutions $X$ which satisfy
$$
X^T D X = D
$$
Certainly $X = \pm I$ satisfy the equation, but how does one find all the nontrivial solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X^TDX=D$ means that $(D^{1/2}XD^{-1/2})^T(D^{1/2}XD^{-1/2})=D^{-1/2}X^TDXD^{-1/2}=I$. Therefore the general solution is given by $X=D^{-1/2}QD^{1/2}$ where $Q$ is any orthogonal matrix.

Comment: how could you think of this method? Is there any reference or basis for that?

Comment: @WeijunYin It's a simple change of variable. There is nothing mysterious about it.